# Cambio de status en PHP

Tags: php, api, sql

Estoy haciendo una `api` para cambiar el `status` de un item dentro de un inventario, por ciertos procesos se puede aplicar el cambio.

```js
else if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['x']))
    {
    
       $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
    
        $query1 = 'SELECT quantity-2, reorder_Level FROM inventory_list WHERE id= ?';
        $result1 = $connection->executeQuery($query1,array($_POST['id']));
        echo $result1[0][0];
        echo $result1[0][1];
    
         if (intval($result1[0][0]) == intval($result1[0][1]))
           {
            $query = 'UPDATE inventory_list SET status = 2 WHERE  id = ?';
            $result = $connection->executeNonQueryWithReturn($query,array($_POST['id']));
           }
            else
            {
            $query = 'UPDATE Supplies SET status = 1 WHERE  id = ?';
            $result = $connection->executeNonQueryWithReturn($query,array($_POST['id']));
            }
                    if ($result == 1)
                    {
                      echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => '0',
                        'errorMessage' => 'articulo cambio status'
                      ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => '2',
                        'errorMessage' => 'articulo no cambio status'
                      ));
                    }
              }
    
        else if(isset($_POST['id']))
          {
    
        $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
        $query1 = 'SELECT quantity, reorder_Level FROM inventory_list WHERE id = ?';
        $result1 = $connection->executeQuery($query1,array($_POST['id']));
    
         if (intval($result1[0][0]) <= intval($result1[0][1]))
         {
              $query = 'UPDATE inventory_list SET status = 3 WHERE  id = ?';
              $result = $connection >executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['id']));
         }
         else
         {
         $query = 'UPDATE inventory_list SET status = 0 WHERE  id = ?';
         $result = $connection->executeNonQuery($query,array($_POST['id']));
           }
    
              if ($result == 0)
              {
                echo json_encode(array(
                  'status' => '0',
                  'errorMessage' => 'articulo cambio status'
                ));
              }
              else
              {
                echo json_encode(array(
                  'status' => '2',
                  'errorMessage' => 'articulo no cambio status'
                ));
              }
    
        }
```

Esto es en base a `quantity` y `reorder_level(cantidad minima)`, en el primer query estoy tratando de que cambie a status `2` si mi quantity actual esta apunto de acabarse con diferencia de `2`, por eso le resto esa cantidad desde un inicio.

Ejemplo: Si mi `reorder_level` es de `2` y mi quantity actual es de `4`, restandole `2` desde un inicio este seria igual a mi cantidad minima en stock por lo que hay una diferencia de `2` para que este se acabe, y cambie el `status` a 2.
De no ser asi cambia a `status` `1`.

En el siguiente `else if` si mi quantity es igual o menor a mi `reorder_level` entonces cambia a `status 3`, por que esta por debajo del minimo, de no ser asi entonces cambia a `status 0`

> 0 = el articulo se encuentra inactivo.
>
> 1 = el articulo se encuentra activo.
>
> 2 = el articulo esta apunto de acabarse.
>
> 3 = el articulo esta por debajo de su minimo.

En codigo no da error alguno, ejecuta pero no cumple la funcion, no cambia `status`, los procesos intermedios pueden ser que agreguen mas unidades a `quantity` o se quiten. Es ahi cuando ejecuta el `api`.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Veo que esto tiene relación con otra pregunta que respondí sobre Javascript. Aquí para simplificar, puedes hacer algo parecido a lo que te sugerí en aquella pregunta, puedes manejar un array o incluso un JSON anidado con cada clave numérica y dentro lo que haya que hacer según cada valor. Así te quitarás de encima todos los `if` que haces una y otra vez y que producen un código difícil de analizar. Ahora bien, viendo que tienes `UPDATE` y `SELECT` mezclados entiendo que es un caso más complejo y que se necesita entender bien el contexto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que me sugeriste en la pregunta anterior eso lo aplique en el JS y funciona bien peor solo si cambio desde la base de datos el status ,me pone el color correcto, pero si desde la interfaz resto, no hace ningun cambio y sigue manteniendo el mismo color.

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que dices sobre la interfaz y la base de datos. No sé si entendiste bien el concepto, se trata de buscar (en la fuente que sea, la base de datos, la interfaz...) el valor del status: `1,2,3,4...` y en base a esa valor obtener el color, el título, etc. Es evidente que si en el código no comparas el objeto contra los valores que se obtienen en la interfaz nada cambiará. Lo importante es que entiendas el concepto, luego la forma de aplicarlo será muy simple y depende de ti. La pregunta era muy larga para poder analizar y comprender todo el contexto...

Comment: En cuanto a esta pregunta no se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres hacer. Afirmaciones como esta son confusas: *Esto es en base a quantity y reorder_level(cantidad minima), en el primer query estoy tratando de que cambie a status 2 si mi quantity actual esta apunto de acabarse con diferencia de 2, por eso le resto esa cantidad desde un inicio.* Eso de que *si mi quantity actual esta apunto de acabarse con diferencia de 2* no se entiende. Y así más cosas que tratas de explicar pero que no se entienden del todo. Además, viendo que sólo es parte de un `else if`  me temo lo peor...

Comment: ... por lo peor quiero decir que quizá tienes un código larguísimo, lleno de `if ... else if` el cual debes ir pensando en optimizar y simplificar con prácticas como las que te expliqué en la otra respuesta: usando estructuras de datos (arrays, json, base de datos...) que guarden tus opciones y haciendo referencia a ellas por índices numéricos. ¿Qué ganas con eso? Supongamos que tienes que comparar entre `n` opciones, digamos que `n=10`... en vez de usar 10 `if`, solamente obtienes el valor numérico del índice y en base a ese valor buscas los otros datos. Ese es el **concepto** del que hablo.